# Dir.pwd() returns nil in Rspec test?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am working on a Ruby application which needs to have a specific directory structure to work properly. To make sure this is the case, I create some temporary directories for testing (rspec). I am attempting to save the current directory, and restore it after the test is done, but it looks like `Dir.pwd()` returns nil. Is it possible not to have a current directory? This isn't documented anywhere...

Code:

```
before :each do
  # make a directory to work in
  @olddir = Dir.pwd()               #=> returns nil???
  @dir = Dir.mktmpdir('jekyll')
end

after :each do
  Dir.chdir(@olddir)                #=> this fails
  FileUtils.rm_rf(@dir)
end

it "should not blow up" do
  1.should == 1
end
```

If I change it to this it works fine, but it seems like bad form to change to the home directory for no reason:

```
before :each do
  @dir = Dir.mktmpdir('jekyll')
end

after :each do
  Dir.chdir()                      #=> works, but feels wrong
  FileUtils.rm_rf(@dir)
end

it "should not blow up" do
  1.should == 1
end
```

Comment: How did you install ruby? If you run `Dir.pwd` from irb what result you will get?

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?  This code works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, because I figured out what was wrong. I should have included the whole test (duh), which looked more like this:

```
context 'one' do
  before :all do
    # make a directory to work in
    @dir = Dir.mktmpdir('foo')
  end

  after :all do
    FileUtils.rm_rf(@dir)
  end

  it 'should not blow up' do
    1.should == 1
  end
end   # end context 'one'

context 'two' do
  before :each do
    # make a directory to work in
    @olddir = Dir.pwd()
    @dir = Dir.mktmpdir('bar')
    Dir.chdir(@dir)
  end

  after :each do
    Dir.chdir(@olddir)
    FileUtils.rm_rf(@dir)
  end

  it "should not blow up" do
    1.should == 1
  end
end   # end context 'two'
```

The problem (now of course, it is obvious) was that I was removing the `pwd`, and getting an `ENOENT` because the current directory had been unlinked. This isn't documented in Ruby, because it's a filesystem error and not an error in the Ruby code.

The lesson, I suppose, is that rspec doesn't create a new running environment from scratch in each new test (as I assumed it did). Lesson(s) learned.